# React - can't setState values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm new to React

when I'm down my soul so weary, troubles come to my code.
because i can't set the state of the addTodo function.
can't add new value to tasks.

my code here:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const tasks = [
      { title: "First Proejct", id: 0 }
    ]
    this.state = {
      tasks,
      uniqueId: 1
    }

  }

  addTodo = (title) => {
    const {
      tasks,
      uniqueId
    } = this.state;

    const task = {
      title,
      id: uniqueId,
    }

    const newTasks = [...tasks, task]

    this.setState({
      newTasks,         <-- HERE. :(
      uniqueId: uniqueId + 1
    })
    console.log(newTasks)
    console.log(task)

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todoApp">
        <h1>ToDO APP</h1>
        <TodoInput addTodo={this.addTodo} />
        <TodoList tasks={this.state.tasks} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

so..

anything that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should invoke:

```
this.setState({
  tasks: newTasks,
  uniqueId: uniqueId + 1
});
```